# Error building an react-native-project in iOS in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**/Users/saan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OneLove-cskgyiozdcaltgbjjotkgypwdqsp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/OneLove.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OneLove.build/DerivedSources/OneLove_vers.c module map file '/Users/saan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OneLove-cskgyiozdcaltgbjjotkgypwdqsp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-geolocation-service/react_native_geolocation_service.modulemap' not found**

This is the error I am facing while trying to build the project in Xcode, I tried many ways to resolve this, but the issue still persists.Not so sure what's the issue with this "react-native-geolocaiton-service". Will be happy if anyone helps me out.

Comment: What version of react are you using? What version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

1)Delete derived data in Xcode>Settings>Locations>Derived data

2)cd ios && pod repo update

then run app using xcode

Comment: Still the same issue, Dint work.